# File Validation using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I have a script which scans a directory and outputs basic raster data information such as the file name, format, number of bands, and etc. I need a way to make it so if the directory does not contain raster data (i.e., anything other than raster data), a message is displayed stating that the directory doesn't have the correct data type.

I know ArcPy has a `Describe()` function that I could use to determine the type of data in a folder, but am not sure how to implement it. This is what I have so far:

```
rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "ALL")
filesType = arcpy.DataType('RasterDataset') # Can use `DatasetType` as well. 
                                            # I've tested this function to describe
                                            # raster data and ArcPy prints out
                                            # 'RasterDataset', that is why I have it 
                                            # there in the brackets.
for name in rasterList:
    if rasterList == filesType:
        print ("\nFilename:"), name
    else:
        print ("This directory does not contain any raster data.")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about something simple like:

```
if len(rasterList) == 0:
    print ("This directory does not contain any raster data.")
else:
    # Your raster processing code
```

The `len()` function calculates the length of the returned string/list, so if it returns `0` then you know nothing in the folder matched the criterion (in this case, being a raster). This way, if the folder contains any rasters (even if not every file is a raster) they will be processed.

Comment: Thanks nmpeterson! That was it. I knew I was missing something simple. Can't believe I didn't think of the `len()` function.